# Constraining vertices in the Z axis when array, curve and shrinkwrap modifiers applied

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, constraints

I'm creating a road on a 3D landscape.  The road's path is defined in the X and Y axes using a bezier.  I've created a small section which I'm then applying to the bezier using an array modifier and then a curve modifier.
To make the road follow the landscape, I'm applying a shrinkwrap modifier to it using project mode on the Z axis.

The issue is that where the road curves around on a sloping hillside, one side of the road is lower than the other.

What is the best solution to make the road level please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using the shrinkwrap modifier on the bezier so it followed the terrain, then I simply applied the road section to the bezier using the array and curve modifiers.
Set the bezier twisting setting to 'Z-Up'.
It was necessary to hit 'apply' to the shrinkwrap modifier on the bezier, otherwise the road simply followed it in 2D.
I hope that helps someone.